# Why does SQL Server Profiler trace not capture SELECT operator in execution plans?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, profiler

When I run `SELECT` queries in SSMS and choose Include Actual Execution Plan, it always includes the SELECT operator. Nice because I can see the full properties like memory grants, cached plan size, subtree cost, etc.

When I run a trace with SQL Server Profiler and grab execution plans via the `Performance > Showplan XML Statistics Profile` event, I get all the operators except for the `SELECT`. Even when I extract to a file and view the plan in SSMS, it's the same--no `SELECT` operator. Is this expected behavior for that particular event? Should I be using some other event to capture the `SELECT` operator and its details?

I'm running Profiler from SSMS version 2014, doing traces against a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

Also wondering how to capture stats to a trace that I'd get from running `SET STATISTICS IO` in SSMS. Or should that already be in the XML Showplan somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Do not run profiler while grabbing execution plans (very expensive operation !), instead run a [server side trace](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/7856994e88dc91f1f175) (modify as per your need) or [sp_whoisactive](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) and grab the tsql you are interested and then run the tsql separately using Plan explorer to get actual execution plan.

The **best way** to get all the relevant data is to run the query from [sql sentry's plan explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) (its free - but worth spending a little money on Pro version).

The free version is sufficient as it gets you the Table IO (same like stats IO ON) along with Plan diagram, statements tree, plan tree and top operations, etc