# Why execution plan could be skipped from XE session?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, trace

Got an issue, similar to this one: [Why does SQL Server Profiler trace not capture SELECT operator in execution plans?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/147886/30929). There was an advice to use XE instead of Trace, but it does not help.
Thing is, the same problem repeats on SQL Server 2016 with Extended Events.

I need to investigate a query from within a batch. This batch involves some temporary tables, so I can’t just catch a query from the middle and put it into Management Studio, Plan Explorer or any other app. So, the next idea was to watch it “in a wild”, gathering all the needed telemetry.

At first, I’ve set a Trace with “RPC completed”, “SP Statement completed” and “Showplan XML Statistics Profile” events. Everything went great except… **I didn’t get just one plan – the plan I needed** – because it was “skipped”.

Then I set an XE session with the same events: “rpc_completed”, “sp_statement_completed” and  “query_post_execution_showplan”. I set “no data loss” policy (I know, it hurts, but I needed answers and it’s dev-box anyways). But… still the same result.

[image: plan missing]

All the sessions had 2 filters: by application name and by database id. I can’t see any good reason, why some plan just gets “skipped”. Maybe, someone can point me at what I am missing?

Comment: Try removing the database ID filter.  And may as well remove the application name filter too while you're troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Why not use the Query Store? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: Few updates: 
1. Removing filters did not work -- plan is still missing, which is strange
2. Thanks for spotting on Query Store! I completely missed such an option. I found my plan there, but there's one thing: QS shows estimated plans without actual execution stats. I can see why it works that way, but this does not solve my current case: to get actual stats and find out, what I can improve.